# Join same table twice on different key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a two tables `accounts` and `subs`.
The first table has `id` and the second table has fields `id`, `requester_account_id`, `grabber_account_id`

I want the count of how many sub requests an account made, and how many grabs he did (based on if the `requester_account_id/grabber_account_id` is populated with his `id`)

**In one query**

output:

```
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
| account_id | subs_requested | subs_grabbed    |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1         | 4              | 3               |
|  3         | 2              | 1               |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Creating a terse testcase is for _your_ benefit, not ours.

Comment: As grandma would say: "I don't like your tone, mister"

Comment: @Tomalak, ....????? I don't find any problem with this question, it is clearly formulated and can be clearly answered. I don't see why we would need the testcase. No reason for downvoting the question at all!

Comment: Tomalak is a purist.  He prefers too much information to too little.

Comment: @Tomas: I did not downvote the question. It's fine. (When I downvote a question, I write a comment along with the text "-1".) I am merely making a comment relating to what used to be the first line of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like

```
select accounts.id, 
    count(distinct s1.id) as num_req, 
    count(distinct s2.id) as num_grab
from accounts left join subs as s1 on accounts.id = s1.requester_account_id
    left join subs as s2 accounts.id = s2.grabber_account_id
group by accounts.id
```

The trick is to use table `subs` twice: `subs as s1` and `subs as s2`, every time joined by different field....

Note regarding efficiency: I'm not sure but I believe this solution is faster than the subquery solution, not tested it though (at least it won't be slower). I always prefer `left join` over subquery whenever possible.

Comment: That seems to be the cleanest way, although I would caution that I have encountered times when aggregate functions in MySQL do not behave as expected on left join conditions.  Make sure your results make sense before going into production.

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks for comment. The potential problems you speak about are probably consequences of NULL values in left joins, but that won't be a problem with `count()` aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @TomasT. It is partially working - 

some values are correctly populated in both columns (when either subs_requested or subs_grabbed is 0), 

while others are seemingly show the *product* of the subs_requested and subs_grabbed in both columns if both are non-zero. (if subs_req =6, subs_grabbed =9, it shows as 54 in both columns)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Shikher, my query assumes that you have `NULL` values in `requester/grabber_account_id`, not zeros. Replace zeros with NULLs, it's more clean anyway, and try the query again.

Comment: @TomasT. not sure I understood you.

`requester/grabber_account_id` are essentially the foreign keys from the accounts table - they can't be NULL. On the other hand, I can have an account who has not grabbed any subs i.e. no entries in the subs table with `account_id` = that fellow's id. (similar case with an account who hasn't grabbed anything)

EDIT: `requester/grabber_account_id` stays `NULL` if its not populated. Default is `NULL`

Comment: @Shikher, aha, that means that you can't have NULL values in `requester/grabber_account_id`? OK, I fixed the query - try it now.

Comment: @Shikher - it's easy - you just join the table twice using `requester/grabber_account_id` and then you just count number of unique rows in subs table which fulfil that condition.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.account_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subs WHERE requester_account_id=a.account_id) AS subs_requested,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subs WHERE grabber_account_id=a.account_id) AS subs_grabbed
FROM accounts a
```

Comment: I wonder if this solution couldn't be slower than the 2 left joins as in my answer. I use to prefer the join solution over the subquery solution whenever possible.

Comment: Actually I think you solution will not give the expected results. The COUNT(DISTINCT...) combined with the WHERE should give 0 or 1 on all rows. I haven't tried it, but that's what I'd expect. As for speed of SUBSELECTS... it depends on the engine and indexes. But I don't think that the question here mentioned speed issues.

Comment: you are right, thanks! The `distinct` shouldn't be there. I want to count all non-null values. I corrected my solution.

Comment: Thank you @Frazz. This works correctly!
Though I am looking for a join solution since the other half of the query (to determine the account ids) is a little more complex.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand what you're looking for, it would be something like this:

```
select
    a.id as account_id,
    count(distinct sr.id) as requests,
    count(distinct gr.id) as grabs
from
    accounts a
left outer join subs sr
    on sr.requester_account_id = a.id
left outer join subs gr
    on gr.grabber_account_id = a.id
```

On occasion, I have experienced weirdness with MySQL when doing aggregate functions on left joins, so here's another way:

```
select
    a.id as account_id,
    (select count(distinct sr.id) from subs sr where sr.requester_account_id = a.id) as requests,
    (select count(distinct gr.id) from subs sr where gr.grabber_account_id = a.id) as grabs
from 
    accounts a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the subs table only once if you want (not sure this performs better)

```
select 
acc.id
sum(if(sub.requester_account_id = acc.id, 1, 0)) as req,
sum(if(sub.grabber_account_id = acc.id, 1, 0)) as grab
from subs sub, accounts acc
where sub.requester_account_id = acc.id or sub.grabber_account_id = acc.id
group by acc.id
```