# Creating View: Multiple Foreign Key Relations to Single Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table, tblNoComp, that has two columns, both foreign keys pointing to tblPackage.ID. The purpose of tblNoComp is to store which packages are not compatible with each other, by simply storing the ID of those packages in two columns, `OneID` and `TwoID`.

May not be the best way of storing it, but since multiple packages aren't compatible with others, it seemed to be the most logical.

Attempting to create a view that shows the tblPackage.Name for the two side by side - I have the following, but unsure how to get the `TwoID` Package Name..

SELECT `tblNoComp`.`OneID`, `tblPackages`.`Package`,`tblNoComp`.`TwoID`,`tblPackages`.`Package`
FROM tblNoComp, tblPackages
WHERE (`tblNoComp`.`OneID` = `tblPackages`.`PID`)

Currently the second `tblPackages`.`Package` is simply showing OneID name, not TwoID.. Not sure how to resolve?

Thank you!

--Apologies if a simple question, I've searched for an hour but haven't quite been able to describe my problem correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you join on the same table, twice, in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199953/how-do-you-join-on-the-same-table-twice-in-mysql)

Comment: To give a summary, what you essentially need to do is "alias" the joined table in the query so that you can join it twice under two names (on two keys). Essentially treating the same table as two separate joined tables.

Comment: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3201359/328193 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7515202/328193 and http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,190885

Comment: While those examples are spot on the same as my problem, I am having great difficulty applying those answers to my problem, since I have used a WHERE statement and not a LEFT JOIN. I've been trying to get a simple LEFT JOIN to work for the past 1/2 hour but running into constant error codes - care to point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: If for no other reason than readability, I'd recommend using joins instead of where clauses to join a table. As for continuing to assist, update your question to show your current attempt(s) to make this work. We can't help you further refine your code if we don't know what your code looks like at this point.

Comment: No worries David - I understand the left join is definitely better. This is my code, as far as it works - I'm still playing with it to get the fourth column to populate using your examples..

Comment: SELECT
    tblNoComp.OneID, 
    tblPackages.Package AS OneIDPackageName,
    tblNoComp.TwoID,
    tblPackages.Package AS TwoIDPackageName
FROM
    tblNoComp
    
LEFT JOIN tblPackages
    ON tblNoComp.OneID=tblPackages.PID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have in your comment:

```
SELECT
  tblNoComp.OneID,
  tblPackages.Package AS OneIDPackageName,
  tblNoComp.TwoID,
  tblPackages.Package AS TwoIDPackageName
FROM
  tblNoComp
  LEFT JOIN tblPackages
    ON tblNoComp.OneID = tblPackages.PID
```

Is aliasing the columns instead of the tables.  The idea behind the aliasing is to `JOIN` the same table twice as two different tables, using two different aliases.  You're only joining it once and trying to *use* it twice.

You probably intent something more like this:

```
SELECT
  tblNoComp.OneID,
  tblOnePackages.Package AS OneIDPackageName,
  tblNoComp.TwoID,
  tblTwoPackages.Package AS TwoIDPackageName
FROM
  tblNoComp
  LEFT JOIN tblPackages AS tblOnePackages
    ON tblNoComp.OneID = tblOnePackages.PID
  LEFT JOIN tblPackages AS tblTwoPackages
    ON tblNoComp.TwoID = tblTwoPackages.PID
```

(Note that I don't have a MySQL syntax checker handy, so this may need to be tweaked in order to run properly.)

Note that the same table is joined twice on two different keys, and that each time it's given a different alias so that it can be referenced within the `SELECT` clause as two separate tables.

Comment: Amazing - it works perfectly. I'll need to study this more, as I now see where you have defined the two alias. Thanks so much.